# Cannot convert string to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

```cs
var result = 0;
try
{
    var MaxID = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
                .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["Id"].Value));
    result = (MaxID + 1);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Label6.Text ="Err " + ex ;
}
```

[image: The Error]

How can i fix that error? I am new to ASP.NET

Comment: use `.Select` first to convert to an int then call max.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: Are you certain that all rows contain a valid integer?

Comment: Yep, Id doesnt nullable and its type is integer.

Comment: I bet the header row is also taken into account. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @uyku The value do they have decimal points?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would help you:

```
var result = gridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
            .Select(r =>
            {
                _ = int.TryParse(r.Cells["Id"].Value?.ToString(), out var numeric);
                return numeric;
            }).Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

> var MaxID = GridView1.Rows.Cast()
> .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["Id"].Value));

Please note that `r.Cells` would return TableCellCollection object, you use r.Cells["Id"] to access specific cell instead of use index of cells, which would cause the error, like below.

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

To fix it, you can check the datasource that you use to populate the `GridView1`, so that you can find the actual index of Id column in your datasource, then you can use that index to access the cell.

For example, I populate the GridView with this source.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Rows.Add(1, "N1");
dt.Rows.Add(2, "N2");

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I can get the cell(s) populated with Id field using this code snippet.

```
var result = 0;
try
{
    var MaxID = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
                .Max(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Text));
    result = (MaxID + 1);

    //...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with a `Parse()` method

```
var result = 0;
        try
        {
            var MaxID = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
                        .Max(r => Int32.Parse(r.Cells["Id"].Value));
            result = (MaxID + 1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label6.Text ="Err " + ex ;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't works 

Comment: Maybe specify a bit. What doesn't work? What is the output/error message?

Comment: Error CS1503 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' myProject1

Comment: Your error _"cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'"_ would tend to indicate that at least one value in the ID column of your grid is not a string containing an integer. Try `Select`ing the results of `int.TryParse` and seeing where `false` shows up